# ExtJS grid - huge delay while deselecting 'select all' check box in case of more than 10K records in the grid. How to reduce this delay?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd, extjs6-classic

I am using Ext version 6.0.1.250. The issue is reproducible when there are > 10K records in the grid.

Here is the [Fiddle Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qf9&view/editor)

Answer (score 0):

Working with store data is faster, but you have to create and customize a **checkcolumn** yourself.

I forked your [Fiddle Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qfp&view/editor) to get you started.